# Swift Fetch and Parse Fixed Width Text File

Tags: ios, xcode, combine

I'm trying to download a text file that has fixed width data elements and create
an array of data (eventually I would store this in Core Data).

This is an example of the data in this file:

USC00054542  37.2000 -103.4833 1770.9 CO KIM 5 SW
USC00054546  37.1150 -103.2986 1602.3 CO KIM 10SSE
USC00054584  39.2833 -104.4333 1937.0 CO KIOWA 5 SE
USC00054585  39.3000 -104.5167 1998.0 CO KIOWA 4 SW
USC00054592  39.6167 -102.5833 1220.1 CO KIRK
USC00054603  38.7658 -102.8031 1311.2 CO KIT CARSON

I created a struct for the object that would be on each line:

```
struct RawStation: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var station: String
    var lat: String
    var long: String
    var elevation: String
    var name: String
    var region: String
    var postal: String
}
```

I tried several ways of decoding this file but have had no success. Here is the 
attempt to use the PropertyListDecoder

```
class Webservice {
    func fetchTextFile() {
        let stationURL = URL(string: "https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt")!
        var s: [RawStation]?

        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: stationURL) {
          let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
          s = try? decoder.decode([RawStation].self, from: data)
        }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: stationURL)
            let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
            s = try decoder.decode([RawStation].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            // Handle error
            print(error)
        }
        print(s as Any)
    } 
}
```

The error message: 
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not a valid property list.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected character A at line 1" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character A at line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Expected ';' or '=' after key at line 1" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Expected ';' or '=' after key at line 1}})))

The url for the file is "https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt"

Sadly, the data does not appear to be available as a JSON file.

Xcode 11.4.1 Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codable isn't going to work for you here because this isn't a structured data format. Unfortunately you're going to have to download the file and then create a parser to decode each line of the file and use that to create your individual data items.

Take a look at `NSScanner` which might help you.

I took another quick look and it's easier than that. The format is documented:

```
Variable   Columns   Type
------------------------------
ID            1-11   Character
LATITUDE     13-20   Real
LONGITUDE    22-30   Real
ELEVATION    32-37   Real (-999.9 indicates a missing value)
STATE        39-40   Character (US stations only)
NAME         42-71   Character
GSN FLAG     73-75   Character (Optional)
HCN/CRN FLAG 77-79   Character (Optional)
WMO ID       81-85   Character (Optional)
------------------------------
```

So you just need to extract the data from those string ranges and use it to create your properties.

Comment: Understood. I will check out Scanner. I seem to remember from a previous attempt that I could use Scanner to parse delimited files, but not fixed width.

Comment: Fixed width is quite easy, and you may not even need a scanner since you know the range of the string that contains the data you want.

Comment: Ahhh. Understood.